# MY pc's zero (0) keyboard button not working as it should under windows

Tags: keyboard

Hello I installed Windows 64 bit to switch from 32 bit to a new system (PC), but now my zero keyboard button is not working as expected. This button is not on the numpad, it is on the left side of my keyboard.

It does not post a zero number, it just unfocuses all programs when pressed! I don't know why it is happening. I used a program called "FocusStealer" which logs what application is stealing focus. Here it logs that `explorer.exe` is stealing it onkeypress. What should I do to solve the problem?

I tried: changing from hungarian keyboard to english: same as in hungarian: the zero number unfocuses instead of typing zero.

Here is what it sais when I press the zero key:

> Lost at 2014.12.04. 17:41:02 due to: C:\Windows\Explorer.EXE

Answer (score 0):

I solved it. It was **WinFast TV** software that cause the zero button to work unexpectedly.